# Can't set width of column in bar chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm working with Google Bar Charts. In the left side, I need to add the description of the bars.

1. Move within USA
2. Received in New Jersy
3. Handed over to International
4. Currier At Sri lanka port

But I can't show the whole sentence in the bar chart. Below I attached the bar chart and the code

[image]

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", {role: "style"}],
        ["Move within USA",parseInt(orderObj.RNJ), "color :blue"],
        ["Received in New Jersy", parseInt(orderObj.HOC), "color :yellow"],
        ["Handed over to International Currier", parseInt(orderObj.ASP), "color :red"],
        ["At Sri lanka port", parseInt(orderObj.KWH), "color: green"]
                            ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
         {
          calc: "stringify",
          sourceColumn: 1,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation"
          },
          2]);

    var options = {
         title: "",
         width: 600,
         height: 300,
         bar: {groupWidth: "65%"},
         legend: {position: "none"}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart_divSea1"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
```

Comment: @kabanus I already upload a image.

Comment: @kabanus yes now look like good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adjusting it using `left` and `width` of `chartArea` as follows?

```
var options = {
  title: "",
  width: 600,
  height: 300,
  bar: {groupWidth: "65%"},
  legend: {position: "none"},
  chartArea: {left: 250, width: 300} // Added
};
```

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var orderObj = {RNJ: 6, HOC: 26, ASP: 6, KWH: 14}; // sample values

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density", {role: "style"}],
    ["Move within USA",parseInt(orderObj.RNJ), "color :blue"],
    ["Received in New Jersy", parseInt(orderObj.HOC), "color :yellow"],
    ["Handed over to International Currier", parseInt(orderObj.ASP), "color :red"],
    ["At Sri lanka port", parseInt(orderObj.KWH), "color: green"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }, 2]);

  var options = {
    title: "",
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    bar: {groupWidth: "65%"},
    legend: {position: "none"},
    chartArea: {left: 250, width: 300} // Added
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart_divSea1"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_divSea1"></div>
```

#### Reference :

- [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.